# Any homeomorphism from the closed disk $E^2$ to itself maps $S^1$ onto $S^1$ and $U^2$ onto $U^2$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Any homeomorphism from the closed disk $E^2$ to itself maps $S^1$ onto $S^1$ and $U^2$ onto $U^2$.

I think I can argue as follows: Points in $S^1$ can't be sent into the interior of $E^2$ because $E^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$ while $S^1$ is not. But I am confused as to how to answer the rest of it. Can you help?

Comment: Hint: think about which points of $E^2$ have neighbourhoods homeomorphic to ...

Comment: @RobertIsrael The points in $U^2$ have neighboorhoods homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, and the others do not.

Answer (score 4):

As you added the tag "algebraic-topology", let me write a proof using a bit of fundamental groups.

Note the following fact: if $p \in E^2$, then
$$ \pi_1(E^2-\{p\}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & p \in U^2, \\ 0 & p \in S^1. \end{cases} $$
(I'm being a bit sloppy here, as I'm not fixing a base point, but it is clear that these spaces are path connected, so this doesn't make an issue.)

Now, assume that $f\colon E^2 \to E^2$ is a homeomorphism. This induces homeomorphisms $E^2-\{p\} \to E^2-\{f(p)\}$ for all $p \in E^2$, hence
$$ \pi_1(E^2-\{p\}) \cong \pi_1(E^2-\{f(p)\}). $$
From the preceding fact we get that $p \in U^2$ implies $f(p) \in U^2$, and $p \in S^1$ implies $f(p) \in S^1$, as required.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\Bbb{Z}$ if $p\in S^1$? The fundamental group of the circle is $\Bbb{Z}$, no?

Comment: The fundamental group of $S^1$ is the circle, but we are not computing that (directly). We are computing $\pi_1$ of the disk minus $p$. Then, if we remove some point $p \in S^1$, the space $E^2-\{p\}$ is still simply connected.